# Java tokenize a string

Tags: java, regex

I would like to tokenize the following string.
"I went home with Mark's brother, to play a video game."
result should be like this.

```
I
went
home
with
Mark
'
s
brother
to
,
play
a
video
game
.
```

Can you please tell me how to do it using regex.

Comment: do you have some code you tried so far?

Comment: yes the dot is in. and sorry the comma is also in. I just corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want the `,`, `.` and `'` as separate tokens, you could split like this:

```
String str = "I went home with Mark's brother, to play a video game.";
String[] tokens = str.split("(\\s|(?=[,.'])|(?<=[,.']))");
```